# Error 406 :Angular Wrong Accept header is sent

Tags: angular, httpclient, http-status-code-406

Here is my code which is calling a rest endpoint which returns JSON data.

```
return this.http.patch(URL, httpOptions);
```

It's a path request with no request body.

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
})
};
```

though i have specified Accept header as 'application/json' in request. Text/plain is also sent for Accept.

Accept header from Browser. 
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

A patch *should* have a body. The third parameter is the options *after* the body. You have options as a second parameter in place of body which I suspect is causing the issue:

https://angular.io/api/http/Http#patch

Do you posssibly mean to use http.get?